# I can't save the Post. No route matches [POST] "/posts/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs

Hope that this files is enough to solve the problem. All is working I just can't save the post.

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'posts#index'
  resources :posts
end
```

post_controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created post!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Error creating new post!"
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:author, :title, :summary, :body)
  end

end
```

Comment: Please send output from "rake routes"

Comment: `new` is supposed to be for `get` requests not posts(POST request).

Comment: Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
         root GET    /                         posts#index
        posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
              POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
     new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
    edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
         post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Post form code starts like this:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
```

Comment: <%= form_for :post do |f| %>

Comment: change it to <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %> and see what happens. Form helpers take name of instance variable - here "@post" as a parameter.. Read more about form helpers here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: ahahashah I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

You do "GET" for post#new and a "POST" for post#create.
The new action is designed to return the form required to "POST" to the create action. You don't post to the new action.

Comment: I'm new to ROR. How can I fix it?

Comment: How are you going to your post new ? You should have a link that looks like this: new_post_path

Comment: I have it in index.html.erb

Comment: <%= link_to 'New post', new_post_path %>

Comment: Add your "rake routes" output. Did you restart your server ? Also post the form in your new.html file

Comment: Yes I restart server. Yes form in new.html.erb.

Comment: Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
     root GET    /                         posts#index
    posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy

Comment: Please post the form in your new.html. I think the issue is there. Your routes look good.

Comment: <h1>New Post</h1>
<%= form_for :post do |f| %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :author %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :author %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :summary %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :summary %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

Comment: Change your form to: "form_for @post do |f|".